# MATLAB Loop with non-integer Increments and Starting at Index Zero

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing, time, increment

I have the following loop:

```
t_train = 25;
t_wash = 5;

for t = 1:t_train
    if t > t_wash
        X(:,t-t_wash) = L(:,t-t_wash);
    end
end
```

I would like to change the loop to the following:

```
t_train = 25;
t_wash = 5;
dt = (10^-1);

for t = 0:dt:t_train
    if t > t_wash
        X(:,t-t_wash) = L(:,t-t_wash);
    end
end
```

This does not work since I am using a non-integer increment and starting at index 0. Is there a way to do both of these things in MATLAB?

Comment: You can only index using positive integers. What is the goal of the non-integer interval? Do you need to interpolate your data arrays? Are you using `t` for something else besides indexing? —— Also, your example code can be replaced by a single statement, you don’t need a loop for that. Maybe you simplified your code a bit too much for the MRE?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, I use ```t``` for more than just indexing so defining it separately is useful in my case. The goal of the non-integer interval was to improve the versatility of my entire code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

separate between the information your vector contains (in this case time), and the fact that it is a vector of some length. For example, you can define any time vector :

```
t=0:dt:t_max;
```

and loop over its number of elements given by `numel(t)`:

```
for n=1:numel(t)
    if t(n)>t_wash
        X(n) = t(n)-t_wash;
    end
end
```

of course, Matlab can do so much more, such that a for loop is not needed, for example, the statement `t>t_wash` yields a logical vector of 0's and 1's and so you can write `X(t>t_wash)=L(t>t_wash)` to assign the values of L into X in one line...